# jquery .html works but .add doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this.body).html("<p>using .html</p>"); // works
    $(this.body).add("<p>using .add</p>"); // doesn't work
});​
```

[some jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLzw8/)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **append** instead of **add**.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLzw8/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$(this.body).append("<p>using .add</p>")
```

[`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) is for something else:

> Description: Add elements to the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

add() doesn't write to the DOM, it adds more elements to a jQuery object.

```
var x = $("li") //would create a jQuery object
x.add("span") //would add span tags to that object.
```

To write the contents of your jQuery object you want to append() or appendTo()...

```
x.appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 0):

`add` description: `"Add elements to the set of matched elements."` [reference](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

`html` will replace `this.body` content.

`append` will add to the end of the content. Maybe that's what you want.

`$(this.body).append('<p>using .append</p>');`